# Suggested approach to import Palm phone/Palm Desktop address book into my Mac/iTunes/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, import, address-book, palm-desktop

I have an address book/calendar from my old Palm-based smart phone stored in Palm Desktop on my Windows box.

Does anybody have suggestions about how I could go about getting the data onto my Mac/iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

If you can import from Palm Desktop to the system Address Book, then you can just sync that to your phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I discovered that there's no simple export/sync route.  I think easy interoperability is deliberately missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the contacts and calendar to export into gmail/google calendar, you can [sync to the iphone](http://www.google.com/mobile) from that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to do this is to get your palm to sync with outlook address book in your MS email client.  Then once you have the addresses in outlook simply uninstall your palm app.  Congigure iTunes to sync calendars with outlook.  Sync and you are all done.  This worked like a champ for me.  Another method to do this is to import your addresses from PST to your exchange mailbox address list and then sync over the air (OTA) to your mailserver